# How to deploy a backbonejs app to a production server.

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, gruntjs, digital-ocean

I wrote a small single page application in BackboneJS and not sure how to get it into production. I typically use grunt serve command and it runs everything and displays to localhost:9000.

How do I do this on a production server so I can access the app from www.example.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backbone apps are all static files man, so you can put it in a CDN or just have apache/nginx serve them as static files.. Doesnt get any simpler than that really.

1. Get a server
2. Install nginx/apache
3. Configure nginx/apache to use your `example.com` and link it your /path/www/your-backbone-app
4. Copy over your dist/ directory to /path/www/your-backbone-app

> i really suggest you minify the hell out of your html/css/js since you said your backbone app is all one "page". Make 1 js file with everything inside (look into require.js and "r.js").

5. Profit!

Your best choice is to do it all in your computer: *require.js can do all of this automated! ->*. join and minify all that apply, change the html code to reflect the new minified names of the css and js, zip. Finally run this from the console `scp -r ~/yourapp/dist/ server:/path/www/your-backbone-app`. Greatest thing of all this is you dont have to do anything else after that command. Enjoy.